# Jquery replace tags in string

Tags: jquery

I have string such a:

```
"<p>Some text <em>Italic string</em> ... </p><em>Second str</em>"
```

How can I replace all em tags to i tags ?

In result I need:

```
    "<p>Some text <i>Italic string</i> ... </p><i>Second str</i>"
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is ridiculously simple, so you need to show us what you've tried and what didn't work.

Comment: I tried it:`function replace_em_to_i(content) {
        var c = content;
        c =c.replace(/<em>/g,"<i>");
        c =c.replace(/<\/em>/g,"</i>");
        return c;
      }`  
But I am not sure that it is the best solution

Comment: you would try it may help you

var value = $("#abc").val(); 
value = value.replace(/\em/g, 'i');

Answer (score 0):

```js
var replaceTag = "<p>Some text <em>Italic string</em> ... </p><em>Second str</em>";
replaceTag = replaceTag.replace(/<em>/g, "<i>");
replaceTag = replaceTag.replace(/<\/em>/g, "</i>");
console.log(replaceTag);
```